How do I write Float64 out in custom formats?
I need to write data into excel friendly CSV files. It seems like excel takes issues with Float64, in particular NaN and scientific notation. Is there a convenient way of forcing CSV.write  to write Float64 with all digits, and make NaN  into empty strings?

If you use CSV file temporally, you may write data directly to xlsx. See https://github.com/felipenoris/XLSX.jl.

You can use the transform keyword arg in CSV.write.
For example
using CSV, DataFrames


a = DataFrame(a = rand(Float64, 2))

a[1, :a] = NaN

CSV.write("c:/data/plsdel.csv", a, transform = function(col, val)
    isnan(val) ? "" : val isa Float64 ? @sprintf("%f", x) : val
end)

which would result in a file like this
a

0.3908756185339346

BTW These two functions seems to be able to convert floats to strings with many decimal places
x = rand(Float64)
@sprintf("%f", x) # better
string(x) # not as good
repr(x, context=:compact => false) # not as good

